# How do I create a webhook for sendgrid in c#?

Tags: c#, email, http-post, sendgrid, webhooks

I am new to using Sendgrid emails using c# .Net library. Our requirements wants us to track the status of the email like Delivered/Went to Spam/Client opened/reported as spam etc., By looking at the documentations and answers from other users to my previous questions its my understanding that there is no direct way to track the status of the email (like result object).

It would be really helpful if someone can point me to some example/sample codes or documentation/implementation in C# for the following
1) Adding unique parameters while sending the email using send grid API. Can I use a Guid string as my argument
   I am assuming what I am doing below is correct.

```
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
var identifiers = new Dictionary<String, String>();
identifiers["Email_ID"] = "Email_ID";
identifiers["Email_Key"] = "9ebccd0d-67c0-4c28-bbf3-83d5bb69f098";
myMessage.AddUniqueArgs(identifiers);
```

2) How to use event webhooks to get the status with the unique argument that I used above from the http_post so that I can associate an email to the status. Any sample code , documentation in c# or an overall idea of how this works will get me started on this.

Appreciate your time and answers.

Comment: For all others that have the same problem already - https://sendgrid.com/blog/tracking-email-using-azure-sendgrid-event-webhook-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails via SendGrid is easier from C# using the [official library that SendGrid provides](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp). From your code example, it looks like you may already be using this - good job.

The unique argument should work as long as its been stringified, and you're not trying to pass an object to `myMessage.AddUniqueArgs`.

The Event Webhook will send a JSON packet to any URL that you specify. If you have included unique arguments in an email that you send out via SendGrid then these are automatically added to each event response you get back from the webhook - you don't need to turn anything else on to get the arguments as well.

There is an example of this call and the resulting response in the [SendGrid Documentation.](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Unique-Arguments-and-Categories)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any sample appln or code for listening to the post request and processing the Json packet in Asp.net c#?

Comment: @itsfighter Of course, you can find an example here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/Webhook_Examples/csharp.html

Comment: There are some libs out there for this as well: https://github.com/mirajavora/sendgrid-webhooks :)

Answer (score 0):

> SendGrid has an Event Webhook which posts events related to your email
> activity to a URL of your choice. This is an easily deployable
> solution that allows for customers to easiy get up and running
> processing (parse and save) their event webhooks.
>
> This is docker-based solution which can be deployed on cloud services
> like Heroku out of the box.

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/tree/main/examples/eventwebhook/consumer